# something like EVT_OPEN wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to run some code after the window has loaded. I imagined using `EVT_OPEN`, as opposite of `EVT_CLOSE`, to do this, only to find out it doesn't exist.
I have some code that must run after the window has loaded and that updates a gauge in that window. Therefore I can't run it in the `__init__` of the frame. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `EVT_SHOW`

http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ShowEvent-class.html

Note that this event occurs for both show and hide - you need to call GetShow to determine which event occurred.

Or you could do something like this:

`wx.CallAfter(self.update_gauge)` (for example) in your `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

There's [EVT_WINDOW_CREATE](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.WindowCreateEvent-class.html).  From the docs: "The EVT_WINDOW_CREATE event is sent as soon as the window object (the underlying GUI object) exists."

Comment: I tried your answer, but it doesn't work. I used `self.Bind(wx.EVT_WINDOW_CREATE, self.onStartUp)` in the `__init__` of the frame, but `onStartUp` never executes.

Comment: Of course, whether it works depends on how you're using it. With such a thing, for example, it would be easy to Bind the handler after you've created the window, and then, of course, the handler wouldn't be called because the window's already been created.  You probably want to use PreWindow, Create, and PostCreate, instead of the normal route. See, for example, http://wiki.wxpython.org/TwoStageCreation . I think EVT_WINDOW_CREATE is what you said you wanted, but to determine how you'd need to use it, and whether it's the best approach, I'd need to know more about what you want.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, but I used `wx.CallAfter()` after all. This turned out to work fine, and why would I make it more complicated than needed?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is a real question, but, assuming it is: CallAfter and the EVT_WINDOW_CREATE event will do different things at different times, it just depends what you want/need.  CallAfter calls when the current and pending events have been handled, and CREATE will occur when the window GUI exists.  Of course, though, using the simplest thing that works for you is a reasonable approach.

Comment: It was meant as a retoric question, but thanks for the answer anyway :). You're right that they do different things, but doing something when the window is created (`EVT_WINDOW_CREATE`) or doing something after the frame is initialized (`wx.CallAfter()`) practically does the same, or am I understanding something wrong? (You may answer that, but again it isn't really an important question :D)